# using face Id whenever user close the app

Tags: ios, swift, telegram, touch-id, face-id

I'm trying to learn swift and i'm lately I have learned how to add faceID to my application , BUT i wanna go further !  sometimes user minimize the app and it could be in any view controller !  and i want to use faceID next the user start using the app.and when the faceID granted the user , it shows the vc he/she left! I need something like Telegram messenger .

```
        let AUth = LAContext()
    var autherror:NSError?
    AUth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &autherror)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if autherror != nil
    {
        // there is an error : not available
        print("auth is not available on the ios")
    }
    else
    {
        // auth is available
        AUth.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Page contain SENSETIVE content, use your biometric ID to unlock the page.", reply: { ( complete:Bool! , error:Error!) ->Void in
            if error != nil
            {
                //there is an error
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{
                //all set
                if complete == true
                {
                    print("auth successful")
                    // is auth success , goes to next page
                    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstviewPage") as! UITabBarController
                    self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else
                     {
                    //user was not the correct user
                    print("auth failed")
                    //we have an error
                    print(autherror?.localizedDescription ?? "...")
                    //show the normal screen
                    AUth.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &autherror)
                    }
            }

        })


    }
```

and as you can see here when the user open the app for the , it checks if the person is the right guy or not , but i want this functionality even whenever user minimize the app and open it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `LAContext` related code in a function on your app delegate. Then call that function from both `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Comment: just to clarify, I have to make a function  for lacontext in delegate and then call it in the these 2 part you mentioned?